# VB.Net api affects windows forms

Tags: vb.net, api

I am creating a application in vb.net and i am using some API functions.For example : GetForegroundWindow,SetWindowPos .So my app should change the active window's size and position when clicked.But it is affecting also the system forms like taskbar ,  StartMenu.How can i avoid this?

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SetWindowPos(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Integer
End Function ''SETTTING THE WINDOW POSITION
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vKey As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Short
End Function

<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetForegroundWindow() As IntPtr
End Function
Private ReadOnly HWND_TOP As New IntPtr(0)
Public Const SWP_FRAMECHANGED As Integer = &H20


Dim cX As Integer, cY As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    cX = CInt(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X.ToString())
    cY = CInt(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y.ToString())


    If GetAsyncKeyState(1) <> 0 Then
        If cX <= 10 Then
            If GetForegroundWindow() <> 1 Then
                SetWindowPos(GetForegroundWindow(), HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 100, 100, SWP_FRAMECHANGED)
            End If
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: We use API - the form's .Top, .Left properties should move the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32")>
Public Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpdwProcessId As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ID As IntPtr, hWnd As IntPtr '// hWnd By GetForegroundWindow
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, ID)
    If Process.GetProcessById(ID).ProcessName.ToLower <> "Explorer".ToLower Then 'Without.exe
        MessageBox.Show("Set Position")
    End If
End Sub
```